# OpenVPN error opening configuration file

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to connect my laptop to the office network using OpenVPN. I'm using the terminal client of OpenVPN on Ubuntu 21.10. Before I was using the same tool in Ubuntu 18.04 and the setup was working fine and I could connect to the VPN server of my office using the following command.

```
sudo openvpn vpn.office-address.org
username
*******
```

However now after the update I'm getting the following error

```
Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: vpn.office-address.org
Use --help for more information.
```

Fore some reason OpenVPN client thinks that the server address I'm giving is a file name of the configuration file. How can we fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-January/000276.html https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I have updated to Ubuntu 21.10 and still the problem persists.

Comment: have you tried `sudo openvpn --remote vpn.office-address.org` ?